# Validation control with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm actually trying to make my contact form and I want to use jQuery to check empty fields.

I've searched and it seems to be possible with an addClass has the error but I don't know how it's working.

I tried to copy/paste some codes and... Failed

Here's my code:

```
<form id="contactform">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="inputName" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Message</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <textarea class="form-control required" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

How can I do it? When I click on the "send" button, nothing happens.

Comment: Can you post your jquery code that you tried? Also you can add class `has-error`, but that by itself does nothing. `has-error` might have some visual displays to make the errored fields look different. In your validation script you'll still need to prevent the form from submitting with something like `event.preventDefault()` if there are any errors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096904/reset-form-remove-error-classes-from-jquery-validate

Comment: do you mean that is your code in that question, or the code in the fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/bBc8c/1/` is your code? Or you copied that code and it's not doing anything? What do you expect it to do? Send an email? or just show errors at this point?

Comment: I have copy/pasted this code, it's not mine. Actually, i just want to show errors, i'm working on my website, it's not online. I've already link jquery.js and bootstrap

Comment: You should click through to the fiddle they posted `http://jsfiddle.net/bBc8c/1/` notice that all the functions that they simplified for the posting is inside a `$(document).ready(function(){ /*code here*/ });` to start. From there they've set up validation handlers and success handlers. Also it uses a library `jquery.validate` which you'll need if you're copying this method of validation.